# Consistent nomenclature for $\mathbf{E}$-, $\mathbf{D}$-, $\mathbf{B}$-, $\mathbf{H}$-, $\mathbf{P}$-, and $\mathbf{M}$-fields

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, terminology, conventions

The six major players, if you will, in electromagnetism are the fields $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{H}$, and $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{M}$. I have seen many differing names for these fields, as listed below. (I have tried to list exactly two sources that support each name, except when the plethora of sources motivated me to include three or when the insufficiency of sources motivated me to include only one.)

### $\mathbf{E}$

- electric field ([*HyperPhysics*](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefie.html), [College Board](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/physics-c-tables-and-equations-list.pdf))
- total electric field ([*SE* answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/300752/127932))

### $\mathbf{B}$

- magnetic field ([College Board](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/physics-c-tables-and-equations-list.pdf), [*HyperPhysics*](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfie.html), [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field))
- magnetic flux density ([the BIPM](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_summary_en.pdf), [*Encyclopedia Magnetica*](http://www.encyclopedia-magnetica.com/doku.php/confusion_between_b_and_h))
- total magnetic field ([*SE* answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/300752/127932))

### $\mathbf{D}$

- electric displacement field ([*Physics Forums*](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/what-is-the-electric-displacement-field.763099/), [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field))
- free electric field ([*SE* answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/300752/127932))
- electric flux density ([site called *Maxwell's Equations*](http://www.maxwells-equations.com/density/electric-flux.php), [*Your Dictionary*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/electric-flux-density))

### $\mathbf{H}$

- auxiliary magnetic field ([*Physics Pages*](http://www.physicspages.com/2013/07/05/auxiliary-magnetic-field-h/), [a Wolfram source](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/H.html))
- magnetic field ([*Physics Pages*](http://www.physicspages.com/2013/07/05/auxiliary-magnetic-field-h/), [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field))
- free magnetic field ([*SE* answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/300752/127932))
- magnetic field strength ([*Encyclopedia Magnetica*](http://www.encyclopedia-magnetica.com/doku.php/confusion_between_b_and_h))
- magnetic intensity ([*Encyclopædia Britannica*](https://www.britannica.com/science/magnetism/Repulsion-or-attraction-between-two-magnetic-dipoles#ref262395))

### $\mathbf{P}$

- electric polarization ([*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_density), [a Wolfram source](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/ElectricPolarization.html))
- polarization density ([*Physics Pages*](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/06/15/field-of-a-polarized-object/), [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_density))
- bound electric field ([*SE* answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/300752/127932))

### $\mathbf{M}$

- magnetization ([a Wolfram source](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/Magnetization.html), [*Physics pages*](http://www.physicspages.com/2013/06/29/magnetization-bound-currents/), [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization))
- bound magnetic field ([*SE* answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/300752/127932))

My question is: **If I am producing a work that references all six of these fields, what is a cohesive nomenclatorial system (or multiple distinct systems, for that matter), such as your own preferred terminology, that I could use to mention these fields in a way that is consistent with their physical properties and without confusion?** If you have heard any other terms used for these fields, please feel free to mention that! Of course, I will explicitly connect the symbols to the terms I use.

Note: I have intentionally listed the names that I find preferable first. If you concur, go ahead and mention that in the comments if you wouldn’t mind, just so I can feel some sense of following convention.

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as a futile primarily opinion-based endeavor, because different authors use different notations & conventions.

Comment: @Qmechanic How could I change the question? It's a good topic to discuss, and others have already expressed their approval by favoriting and up-voting.

Comment: I asked in the chat room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38370003#38370003).

Comment: @Qmechanic Okay, I like the sound of that. Quick question: what is OP?

Comment: OP=Original Poster. In this case: You.