# Why do polarization & magnetization have opposite effects on $E$ vs $B$?

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization, dielectric

[Students commonly wonder](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/468529/80810) about the near-analogies between electricity & magnetism.  One in particular:

[Polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_density#Definition) $\mathbf{P}$ and [magnetization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization#Definition) $\mathbf{M}$ are the infinitesimal densities of electric and magnetic dipole moments ($\mathbf P = {\mathrm d\mathbf p \over \mathrm d V}$ and $\mathbf M = {\mathrm d\mathbf m \over \mathrm d V}$).  Flux lines exit the positive end of [electric](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/VFPt_dipoles_electric.svg) and [magnetic dipole](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/VFPt_dipoles_magnetic.svg) vectors the same.
Yet $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{M}$ have the opposite effect on the total (= [fundamental](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/difference-between-electric-field-mathbf-e-and-electric-displacement-field) = free + bound charge) fields $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.  Why is the $E$-field lessened by *parallel* electric dipoles, while the $B$-field is greater when it induces *parallel* magnetic dipoles?

Comment: *The $E$-field is lessened by parallel electric dipoles*. Lessened with respect to what?

Answer (score 2):

Because you chose the pair $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$ instead of the pair $\mathbf E,\mathbf H$ and because you assume magnetically paramagnetic or ferromagnetic medium.

If the medium is diamagnetic (copper, bismuth), then its magnetization due to external field *decreases* $\mathbf B$ inside.

If you want to talk about iron or steel, those are ferromagnetic, external field induced magnetization increases field $\mathbf B$ inside. But it decreases field $\mathbf H$ inside.

So there is no general relation/analogy, the relation between external magnetic field $\mathbf B_{ext}$ and medium-induced field $\mathbf B_{ind}$ depends on the kind of material medium.

Comment: Note the parallel between a "diamagnetic" material and a "dielectric," in terms of the relation between the vacuum field and the polarization of the material.

Comment: This is just a restatement of the question, not an answer.  I explicitly chose $\mathbf{M}$ parallel to $\mathbf{B}$ (i.e. paramagnetic) because it’s analogous to $\mathbf{P}$ parallel to $\mathbf{E}$.  Both represent dipoles parallel to the external fields E & B.  I chose E & B because these fundamental quantities include the effects of free *and* bound charges/currents.

Comment: My question is *why* dipoles have opposite effects on the respective total (free + bound) fields.

Comment: @alexchandel So really you just want to understand what the electric field of a dipole is?

Comment: @alexchandel Field $\mathbf H$ isn't any less fundamental than field $\mathbf B$. They differ by density of magnetic moment, which is an objective physical quantity.

Comment: @alexchandel In paramagnetics, $\mathbf H$ behaves like $\mathbf E$ does in dielectrics. In diamagnetics, $\mathbf B$ behaves like $\mathbf E$ does in dielectrics.

Comment: But [other accepted & highly voted answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/difference-between-electric-field-mathbf-e-and-electric-displacement-field) say $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are a pair, and more fundamental at the microscopic level.  I know $\mathbf{B}$ is reduced in diamagnetics, but the question (I've heard) is *why* $\mathbf{m}$ parallel to the external $\mathbf{B}$-field results in an increased field internally, while $\mathbf{p}$ parallel to the external $\mathbf{E}$-field results in a decreased field internally.

Comment: @alexchandel that is a common sentiment with very little justification for it. In electrostatics both $\mathbf D$ and $\mathbf E$ depend on all charges, the simple equation $\nabla \cdot \mathbf D  = \rho_{free}$ does not mean $\mathbf D$ does not depend on bound charges. In microscopic theory, there is no point introducing 4 quantities, 2 are enough, and by *today convention* these are chosen as $\mathbf e,\mathbf b$. If you read older books like Lorentz' Theory of electrons, he uses $\mathbf d,\mathbf h$ in microscopic theory. His results are correct; these are just conventions, preferences.