# Field of an infinitely wide magnetic dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, dipole

[Students commonly wonder](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/468529/80810) about the near-analogies between electricity & magnetism. One such:

The field of an [electric dipole](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/VFPt_dipoles_electric.svg) in the limit of an infinitely wide plane tends to 0 outside the plane ([integrals of E](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/mchutchon/chargedPlanes.pdf) ($=±\sigma/2\epsilon_0$) [cancel outside the plane](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elesht.html)). ​Does a similar infinite-plane limit exist for a [magnetic dipole](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/VFPt_dipoles_magnetic.svg)?  What's the result, or what's a better limit?

[image][image]