# What is the true meaning of the fields $\mathbf D (\mathbf r, t)$ and $\mathbf H (\mathbf r, t)$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

The meaning of the electric field is

$$
\mathbf E = \frac{\text{force}}{\text{unit charge}}
$$
the meaning of the polarization field is
$$
\mathbf P = \frac{\text{electric dipole moments}}{\text{unit volume}}
$$
For the magnetic field is
$$
\mathbf B = \frac{\text{force}}{\text{unit charge moving with unit velocity such that the force is maximum}}
$$
The magnetization field is the
$$
\mathbf M = \frac{\text{magnetic dipole moments}}{\text{unit volume}}
$$

**Question:**

I know the definitions of the fields $\mathbf D$ and $\mathbf H$ as
$$
\mathbf D = \varepsilon_0 \mathbf E + \mathbf P \\
\mathbf H = \frac{1}{\mu_0} \mathbf B - \mathbf M
$$

Is there such a simple meaning for the fields $\mathbf D$ and $\mathbf H$ similar to those of $\mathbf E, \mathbf P, \mathbf B$ and $\mathbf M$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between magnetic fields $H$ and $B$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/300741/whats-the-difference-between-magnetic-fields-h-and-b)

Answer (score 1):

Think flux-density (from Gauss's law):
$$\mathbf D = \frac{\text{free charge on one capacitor plate}}{\text{area of capacitor plate}}$$

Think circulation-density (from Ampere's Law):
$$\mathbf H = \frac{\text{free current in coil}}{\text{length of coil}}$$

Comment: ${\bf H}$ is the force on a unit magnetic monopole --- if you can find one....